# Round Rectangle in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to generate rounded rectangle - following UI in CSS,

[image]

However I am facing some difficulties to generate it.Here is my code snippet

```
ul {
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 10px; 
}

li  {
            overflow: hidden;
}


li:last-child {
    padding:7px;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
    padding:7px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #DDD;
}


    .parent:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: rgb(40,40,40);
}

    .parent:nth-of-type(even) {
        background-color: black;
}


<div>
<ul>
<li class="parent">
    <label class="labeltitle">NAME</label>
    <label id="firstTF">100</label>
    <label class="unitlabels">UNIT</label>
</li>
<li class="parent">
     <label class="labeltitle">NAME</label>
     <label id="secondTF">200</label>
     <label class="unitlabels">UNIT</label>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: and this isn't working... HOW?

Comment: it is not showing me the same fig.

Comment: well, you've got your border definition on the `<ul>`, when it should be on the `<li>`

Comment: Thanks Marc, I have got your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a JSFiddle solution based on your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/shannabarnard/2an76txm/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="parent">
        <label class="labeltitle">NAME</label>
        <label id="firstTF">100</label>
        <label class="unitlabels">UNIT</label>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
         <label class="labeltitle">NAME</label>
         <label id="secondTF">200</label>
         <label class="unitlabels">UNIT</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
      width: 120px;          
}

li  {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    border:1px solid #000;
}

li label {
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding:3px 0;
}
li label.labeltitle {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #CCC;
}
li label.unitlabels {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}
.parent:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color: #555;
}

.parent:nth-of-type(even) {
   background-color: #777;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You put the border on the ul element, instead of the li elements.
You also didnt close the ul

```
li  {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px; 

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Heres a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tsyg465a/

Answer (score 2):

Add style for li as

```
li{
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned already, you need to put the `border` and `border-radius` on the `li` and not the `ul`. Here's a CodePen with some cleaned up code for you: http://codepen.io/trevanhetzel/pen/pJzws

HTML

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="parent">
        <label class="labeltitle">NAME</label>
        <label id="firstTF">100</label>
        <label class="unitlabels">UNIT</label>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
         <label class="labeltitle">NAME</label>
         <label id="secondTF">200</label>
         <label class="unitlabels">UNIT</label>
    </li>
  </ul> <!--you were missing a closing ul tag-->
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;          
}

li  {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}

li:last-child {
  padding:7px;
  border-bottom: 0;
}


.parent:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(40,40,40);
}

.parent:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.parent {
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid rgb(61, 58, 58);
  line-height: 0.8;
  padding: 5px 24px;
}
.parent:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
.parent:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #444;
}
.parent label {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.labeltitle,
.unitlabels {
  color: #fff;
}
.tf {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">
    <label class="labeltitle">NAME</label>
    <label id="firstTF" class="tf">100</label>
    <label class="unitlabels">UNIT</label>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    <label class="labeltitle">NAME</label>
    <label id="secondTF" class="tf">200</label>
    <label class="unitlabels">UNIT</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the rounded edge styles to your `<li>` not the `<ul>`
Also pretty much all of the styles you applied to `<ul>` belong on `<li>`

```
li {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/yhahnL09/) : with additional styles to more closely mimic your desired output